# What's the easiest way to convert a BMP to a PDF in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf, bmp

What's the easiest way to convert a BMP file to a single page PDF using ASP.net? I'm going to generate the 8.5" x 11" BMP in Flash (which means I can manipulate it to make it as easy as possible), then use a POST to upload it to an ASP page, which will convert it to a PDF and redirect the user to the PDF. I don't want to add any margins or anything else, it will be laid out properly in the BMP for full-bleed.

Would it be easier to convert it to PDF in Flash, then upload?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) to create a PDF and insert the image into the document. This can be done all in memory with a final PDF produced to client.

The following is an MVC method, stripped for display, but should see how to do this.

```
[HttpGet]
public FileStreamResult Export(int? ID)
{        
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    Document pdf = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdf, stream);

    pdf.Open();

    PdfPTable tblImage = new PdfPTable(1);
    tblImage.AddCell(Image.GetInstance(LogChart())); //The LogChart method returns image
    pdf.Add(Image);

    pdf.Close();

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Log.pdf");
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Clear();
    Response.OutputStream.Write(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, stream.GetBuffer().Length);
    Response.OutputStream.Flush();
    Response.End();

    return new FileStreamResult(Response.OutputStream, "application/pdf");
}
```